# Prove that a graph is or isn't hamiltonian

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonicity

[image]

Prove that graph is hamiltonian or if it isn't proof that it isn't.

I tried everything from Ore to to Dirac. If I try to prove that it is not hamiltonian, then I can't find which vertices$\in S$ to remove to prove it by $\omega (G - S) > |S|$.

Comment: Have you tried solving it by hand?

Comment: There is no such $S$ here, so you need to use a different criterion.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  the "perimeter cycle" goes through all but three vertices. Can you deform it a bit so it goes through all vertices?